# Why is my discord.py bot not having voice while being hosted on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, discord.py

My bot is all set up and running, everything works, EXCEPT for voice: He joins the channel, but doesnt play audio. I have heard many different claims for what the reason is (no permission to use ffmpeg.exe, missing buildpack, missing dependency, Heroku blocking UDP on free users...) - but i hope that someone here ACTUALLY knows what the problem is, because i couldnt find any definitive reason online.

This is the code of the bot: https://github.com/FlyingThunder/DiscordBot/blob/master/main.py
Everything is working fine on my machine.
This is the only error that Heroku logs gave me:
`2020-07-24T06:28:30.329937+00:00 app[worker.1]: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'res/ffmpeg.exe'`

I already tried adding `https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git` to my buildpacks, and i added `cffi==1.14.0` to my requirements.txt - both solutions that are supposed to fix this exact issue.

Comment: You can't just copy `ffmpeg.exe` and commit that. `.exe` is usually a Windows binary not a Linux.

Comment: yea, i know, thats why i added the buildpack for the ffmpeg, which also didnt work sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To host a music bot on heroku, you need:

- Opus and FFmpeg buildpacks (and python of course):

```
https://github.com/kitcast/buildpack-ffmpeg.git
https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git
```

- The following packages in `requirements.txt`:

```
PyNaCl
wheel
ffmpeg
```

If your problem isn't solved after installings those packages and buildpacks, please share the music part of your code.

Comment: now that i think about it - when i use the FFmpeg buildpack / python lib, how would i import it in the code? currently i just do this: `vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=ffmpegpath, source='res/alle.mp3'))` where `ffmpegpath` is `"res/ffmpeg.exe"` but i wouldnt know what to do when using the buildpack

EDIT: it seems the only thing missing now is specifying where the code gets the FFMPEG exe from, the bot got further than before doing this i think

Comment: Using buildpacks, you don't need `executable=ffmpegpath`, ffmpeg will be added to path and discord.py will be able to use it.

Comment: so its supposed to work without adding it at all? if its in path i thought i would have to load it as an env variable - ill try again without the executable=ffmpegpath
EDIT: oh my god, it works! it was so simple, thank you so much!